# What's the most performant way to select all the siblings with higher index?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an HTML element myElement. I need to select all the elements that have the same parent and are after this element.

I tought about

```
var index = $myElement.index();
var followingSiblings = $myElement.parent().children(":gt(" + index + ")");
```

This works but seems clumsy and not very performant.

**Q:** Is there a more elegant, more pefromant, more beautiful, smarter, more awesomer way to do that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var followingSiblings = $myElement.nextAll();
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TsBJF/)

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/)

Comment: Oh thanks @jesse, I copypasted it from OP and didn't notice the typo. `=]`

Comment: No problem, some jQuery API methods aren't very well known. `=]` The [DOM Traversing](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) section as well as the rest of the API site is really helpful for finding such methods.